# jquery masterpage custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Jquery custom function on masterpage not working

I have a custom function like as follows :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.scrollingCarousel = function (options, i) {
         ...something something
    };

    jQuery.fn.scrollingCarousel.defaults = {
        autoScroll: false,
        autoScrollDirection: 'left',
        autoScrollSpeed: 10000,
        looped: false,
        scrollerAlignment: 'horizontal',
        scrollerOffset: 0,
        scrollSpeed: 'fast',
        beforeCreateFunction: null,
        afterCreateFunction: null
    };
})(jQuery);
```

i am using it in a page which has a masterpage.
i am using it in a page as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel();
    });
</script>
```

i get an error as scrollingCarousel is not recognized.

If i dont use the masterpage the code works fine.

Comment: It would really help if you actually asked a question... You get an unexpected behavior (scrollingCarousel is not recognized). What is the error? What do you need help with? Have you included the appropriate plugins?

Comment: `$(this).('#carousel-demo1')` usage is not correct

Comment: 1. Can you share the code for $.fn.scrollingCarousel?
2. As per @prash, $(this).('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel(); is incorrect.  Did you mean $('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel();?

Comment: you may share a jsbin link . you may directly call $('#id') or $(#id).text() in this case text() may be replaced by any function

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned , the way you are calling your function is not correct

example usage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var a  =   $("#carousel-demo1").scrollingCarousel();
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.scrollingCarousel = function (options, i) {
         alert('something')
    };

    jQuery.fn.scrollingCarousel.defaults = {
        autoScroll: false,
        autoScrollDirection: 'left',
        autoScrollSpeed: 10000,
        looped: false,
        scrollerAlignment: 'horizontal',
        scrollerOffset: 0,
        scrollSpeed: 'fast',
        beforeCreateFunction: null,
        afterCreateFunction: null
    };
})(jQuery);
```